# How to fill a TreeStore with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch-2

Like we know, we cannot save data from a TreeStore in a LocalStorage proxy. I've developed a function that saves this data converting the JSON object in a string.

My problem is when I load this string from the LocalStorage and I try to load a TreeStore with this data. If I use `Ext.getStore('MyTreeStore').setData(MyJsonObject)`, I get a Warning with the next message:

> [WARN][Ext.data.TreeStore#removeAll] getRootNode has been deprecated.
>   Please use getRoot instead.

So, does anybody know how to do that? It's very frustating and I don't know how to get this.

Thank you for your help.